# jsi18n django.catalogue doesn't contain any translated strings (but djangojs.mo does)

Tags: javascript, django, django-i18n

So I just translated a javascript `djangojs.po` file in a django project. Then:

```
./manage.py compilemessages -l fr #correctly creates my djangojs.mo file
```

Edit my urls.py

```
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('my_app',),
}
#add to urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^jsi18n/', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
```

I head over to `http://localhost:8000/jsi18n/` in my browser. I get a nice js file, but the django.catalogue is empty.

```
django.catalog = django.catalog || {};
```

So **where did my translation strings go?**

FYI, translation works fine on my template code with the `django.mo` file in the same directory as `djangojs.mo`. Django 1.9.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post this answer as a monument to my stupidity. Hopefully it's useful for someone else.

I wasn't logged in, and had session authentication enabled. Evidently, `/jsi18n/` isn't a `@login_required` url, but it doesn't pull the strings out of the `django.mo` file until you do login.